# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.linear_model._logistic'

Tags: python, scipy, pickle, logistic-regression, gridsearchcv

I am working on a binary image classification project where I used transfer learning by feature extraction. I trained a Logistic Regression model with  the output of ResNet50 (by discarding its final layer and using the activations behind the final layer from it as features).

During test time while loading that Logistic Regression model I got this ModuleNotFoundError.
The following code shows how I loaded the Logistic Regression model which I've already trained on the activations from ResNet50 model.

```
model_logistic_regression = pickle.load(open(MODEL_PATH, "rb"))
```

Here MODEL_PATH contains the directory to the pre-trained Logistic Regression model.

EDIT: This Logistic Regression model was created by GridSearchCV by the following code:

```
model = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(max_iter = 100000), params, cv = 3, # cv means cross validation
                 n_jobs = N_JOBS)
# db["features"] contains the activations (unrolled) from ResNet50 and db["labels"] contains the corresponding output labels
model.fit(db["features"], db["labels"])
```

Finally the model was written to disk using using the following code:

```
f = open(MODEL_PATH, "wb")
f.write(pickle.dumps(model.best_estimator_))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are working with python3. Because in Python 3, the pickle module is renamed into _pickle. You could use `import _pickle as pickle`

Comment: You should find the details in here. https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#library-changes.